# df.apply() works on part of my df but returns “TypeError: float object is not iterable” on whole df

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

**GOAL:** I have one DataFrame, root_df, with where one column is some words separated by a comma (e.g. “door, panther, salute”) named words.  Then I have another DataFrame, freq_df,  where I have two columns, WORD (string ) and SCORE(float).   What I want to do is create an aggregate column with the score from the second DataFrame, freq_df, that total based on the column in the first DataFrame, root_df.  Let me give you an example.  In freq_df the row with “door” has the score 342388, the word “panther” isn’t in the DataFrame at all, and “salute” has the score 9238.07.  So the column in root_df would be 342388 + 9238.07 which is 351626.07.

**ISSUE:** I have been able to do this using .apply() on a subset of my data, but when I try to get this on the whole data set it returns “TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable”.  I thought maybe this was due to their being a NaN in the “Split words” column so I replaced all the NaN with “ “ to see if that helped and I returned a new error, “TypeError: ("unhashable type: 'list'", 'occurred at index Split words')”.   I am confused why this would work on a subset of my data but not on the whole thing, I thought all Series had the same data type.  Can someone explain what is going on?  Is there a way to return the row that is returning the error?  Any help would be appreciated.

This is the entire code including the DataFrame which come from Wikipedia tables to replicate the issue.  Let me know if their are any questions or issue with my code.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import urllib.request

def get_score(field):
    words_list = []
    for word in field:
        words_list.append(word)

    mask = freq_df['Word'].isin(words_list)

    return freq_df.loc[mask, 'Count (per billion)'].sum()

#Root DataFrame
root_urls = [r"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Greek_and_Latin_roots_in_English/A%E2%80%93G",
        r"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Greek_and_Latin_roots_in_English/H%E2%80%93O",
        r"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Greek_and_Latin_roots_in_English/P%E2%80%93Z"]

root_dfs = []

for url in root_urls:
    dfs = pd.read_html(url, header=0)
    for i, df in enumerate(dfs):
        if df.shape[1] != 5:
            print('Deleted below DataFrame(s):\n', dfs[i].head())
            del dfs[i]
    root_dfs.extend(dfs)

root_df = pd.concat(root_dfs, ignore_index=True)
root_df.replace(to_replace="\[.*?]", value="", regex=True, inplace=True)

#Frequency DataFrame
url = r"https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary:Frequency_lists/PG/2006/04/1-10000"

freq_dfs = pd.read_html(url, header=0)

freq_df = pd.concat(freq_dfs)

#Succesful use of apply
test = root_df.head().copy()
a = pd.DataFrame(columns=test.columns)
a.loc[0] = ['Test', 'Test', 'Test', 'Test', 'door, panther, salute'] # Adding the exact example I gave above
test = pd.concat([test, a], ignore_index=True)
test['Split words'] = test['English examples'].str.split(', ')

test_score = test['Split words'].apply(get_score) # LINE IN QUESTION : SUCCESS
print("\nSuccesful test:\n\n", test_score)

#Unsuccesful use of apply
root_df['Split words'] = root_df['English examples'].str.split(', ')
score = root_df['Split words'].apply(get_score) # LINE IN QUESTION : FAIL
print(score)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to use `apply`. You can get all the words in `English Examples` in one long series and then use `map` to map the value from `freq_df` and then sum up each original list of `English Examples`

```
# First get the score mapping series
score = freq_df.set_index('Word')['Count (per billion)']

# use stack to make one long series of words from
# english examples
stacked_words = root_df['English examples'].str.split(',\s*', expand=True).stack()

# map all the english example words to their score
# and then sum up each group(original row)
stacked_words.map(score).groupby(level=0).sum().fillna(0)

0        56157.78
1            0.00
2            0.00
3            0.00
4            0.00
5            0.00
6            0.00
7            0.00
8            0.00
9            0.00
10           0.00
11           0.00
12       11422.40
13      190547.67
....
```

Comment: Thanks!  My original train of thought was to try to use something like replace but I couldn't figure it out so I had to use .apply().  Just to make sure that I understand .map() correctly basically what it does it takes two Series.  It takes the values from the first Series and replaces them with the values of the second Series where Series1 value = Series2 index.  Is that right?